# How to remove the "Get started with your site" sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Whenever I create a site in Sharepoint Online I get the "Get started with your site" web part. I remove it but it never goes away entirely. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and belongs on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you saved the page after you removed the web part.

[image]